# Open another application with landscape screen in android

Tags: android, android-intent, package, landscape

i biult an app that a part of it use FlashFox Pro to show the flash files.
i use the code below to open FlashFox Pro in my app:

```
Intent webIntent = G.packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("mobi.browser.flfoxpro");
webIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://trc.ir/loadapp.php?li=10101&fn="+file_name+"&ex="+extention+"&rt=11"));
webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
G.context.startActivity(webIntent);
```

i want the FlashFox Pro to be landscape when i open it from my app.
what shoul i do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following line in the relevant activity:

> android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Additionally, before starting the activity, you can use this function:

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: this is not my activity. i open it from my activity. this is FlashFox Pro activity

Comment: @MohsenMorshedi Please try using the function setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); before you call the activity